# Pycharm doent recognize numpy package from previously created conda environment

Tags: windows, pycharm, anaconda, conda

im using Pycharm 2022.2.3.
I have Anaconda Navigator 2.3.2. Created in anaconda a new virtual environment based on python 2.7 called testpy2. Added the numpy package needed to execute a code. I did it from Ananconda Navigator GUI. The installation was succesful. I could see now numpy in my installed package list.

Open Pycharm project, select as interpreter the existing conda environment test2py.
The code is:

```
import random
import numpy as np

print "Hola"
```

The problem is it give the error: ImportError: DLL load failed when importing Numpy.
So I cant execute the program because of numpy.

When i go to see the packages something similar to:

[image]

then i got stuck in loading. Pycharm should recognize and load all the packages in the conda environemnt as shown in the image above, but in my case i got stuck in loading.

Im running on Windows 10 and i dont have any python installed at all

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What channels were used? Mixing `anaconda` and `conda-forge` can lead to DLL issues. Please don't post stock images that aren't yours.

Comment: Well thanks for your help ... the problem is from a student and i dont have access to her computer, so i reproduce the error. And yes as i can remember it has two channels, default and conda-forge....should i delete the conda-forge channel and create a new environment ?